# Having two serperate const with information and matching them up

Tags: adonis.js

This is my first post, and i just started developing, so this question is properly stupid.

I am currently creating an application that pulls two sets of data.

1) All the contact information on business that went out of business in Denmark.
2) All of the customers at the firm i work at.

So the functionality is that every time one of our customers goes bankrupt we get a notification.

I have "successfully" made the query that gets the right information in two separate consts.

But how do i math up the numbers i want?

i will describe it like this in plain english, just so you understand what i mean.

Select every firm where "Employer Identification Number" matches up in the two consts.

I use suquel pro as the database, and adonis js for as the programming language

Comment: I'd like to make sure I understand. You need help with a db request. Isn't that right? What's in the two constants? Can you give me an example? Thx